# React Semanti UI DropDown with onClick Even on individual Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

React Semantic UI has DropDown with properties of OnClick
is it possible to make each selection with different onClick event. Pretty much have each selection to run separate function. so in the following example I need if angular was selected a runs a function that is different than css, or design

```
const options = [
  { key: 'angular', text: 'Angular', value: 'angular' },
  { key: 'css', text: 'CSS', value: 'css' },
  { key: 'design', text: 'Graphic Design', value: 'design' },
  { key: 'ember', text: 'Ember', value: 'ember' },
  { key: 'html', text: 'HTML', value: 'html' },
  { key: 'ia', text: 'Information Architecture', value: 'ia' },
  { key: 'javascript', text: 'Javascript', value: 'javascript' },
  { key: 'mech', text: 'Mechanical Engineering', value: 'mech' },
]

const DropdownExampleMultipleSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown placeholder='Skills' fluid multiple selection options={options} />
)
```

I tried doing onchange but it gives me undefined value

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
        console.log('Dropdown changed ' + e.target.value);
        return;
    }
<Dropdown onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}} />
```

Comment: Maybe inside handleChange you can write switch case with event.target.value to have individual implementation.

Comment: @SaurabhNemade it comes undefined

Comment: handleChange(e, data) will give you values in data.
e._targetInst.return.key should also give you value.

let me make a fiddle quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Sandbox with solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/vvz2yow5k5

```
    class DropdownExampleMultipleSelection extends Component {
      handleChange = (e, { value }) => {
        // array of selected values
        console.log(value);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <Dropdown
            placeholder="Skills"
            fluid
            multiple
            selection
            options={options}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you how does that second argument different than e.target.value?

Comment: why is onclick behave differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values by following:

```
  handleClick = (e, data) => {
    console.log(data.value)
    console.log(e._targetInst.return.key)
  }
```

data.value will give you all selected values while e._targetInst.return.key will give you key of currently changed element.

**Working fiddle:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5b24ux?file=index.js
You can view values on each selection by opening the chrome devtools.

Comment: Thank you so much'